# Angular, ui-router: how to ngShow from Directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sails.js

I'm using a code like this:

https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate/blob/master/frontend/src/app/angular/Directives/NavigationHeader.js

and my template code is this:

https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate/blob/master/frontend/src/app/partials/Directives/NavigationHeader/header.html

**The question:**

How to "ngShow" a "div" from "header.html" only if my ui-router's state is "anon.about"?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the state in your template you can do something like this:

```
ng-show="current == $state.includes('<Your State Name>')"
```

and pass the current as a scope variable as in which state is currently having the directive. This can be done by injecting the $stateParams dependency.

Updated Code:

In header.html

```
<div class="">
  <div data-ng-show="$root.currentStateName=='anon.about'">Test!</div>
  <div>{{$root.currentStateName}}</div>
</div>
```

In app.js:

```
.state('anon.about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: function($rootScope,$state){
              console.log($state.current.name);
              $rootScope.currentStateName = $state.current.name;
            }
})
```

Comment: create a fiddle or better a plunker for your problem and then would be better to code in it and give a proper solution

Comment: I am unable to create a plunker for you. However, my code is the same as what I posted in the question. You can use this code in your PC to try?

Comment: Please, help me. Seriously i'm crying.

Comment: Will come up with a plunker dont worry

Comment: Hi I checked your code, where do you want to have ng-show?

Comment: https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate/blob/master/frontend/src/app/partials/Directives/NavigationHeader/header.html here. I want to put a "div" visible only when a state is, for example: "anon.about". Is it possible?

Comment: @ginolin: As I had suggested, have you tried ng-show="$state.includes('anon.about')" on that div?

Comment: Yes. And nothing. If i put "console.log($state.current);" in NavigationHeader.js I have this: Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}. I think is for this that ngshow doesn't work. Why $state.current is blank? And why if I put console.log($state) in current I find correct $state name and not blank ""??

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/7tzXh/22/ it is working for the top div look for the statement $scope.currentState = $state.current.name where I have injected the $state in the controller.

Comment: Nothing to do. But finally I have my own plunker just for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/zPh50zV1HsJU4mid9NAR Can you fix this?

Comment: Hi @ginolin I have solved your problem in the plunker. The updated code is in the answer

Comment: No. Sorry, but I prefer this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/Spv26uPwJwkV6oJZSC9r?p=preview

Comment: With both solution. But with mine app.js is lighter using only navigationHeader.js.